# "Ищете работу?" или "Ищите работу?"

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "Ищете работу?" или "ищите работу?"?

Answer (score 4):

Если это вопрос, то, наверное, ищете (что делаете?).
А если пожелание, то ищите (делайте!).

Answer (score 1):

**Вы** (что делаете?) **ищете** - форма настоящего времени изъявительного наклонения (от "искать"):
*Что вы ищете в моем шкафу?*
*Ищете способ увеличить продажи в интернете?*

**Вы** (делайте!) **ищите!** - повелительное наклонение.
Эта форма образуется с помощью суффикса ***и***, поэтому перед ***-те*** буквы ***е*** быть не может:
*Ищите да обрящете!*
 *Ищите женщину!*

Получается, что в изъявительном наклонении: ***ищете*** новую работу? (ударение на первом И);
в повелительном наклонении: ***ищите*** новую работу! (ударение на втором И).

Правильно будет: ***ищете работу?***
[**Ищете? Ищите!**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%98%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5&limitstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Если ударение на первом слоге - пишется е, если на втором - и.